# draggable html objects with fixed positions

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

I'm not actually sure what to tile this but I'm trying to replicate draggable icons like the iOS home screen. I am not using JQuery. I could figure out how to make things draggable but I don't know how I would implement set positions that the icons would go to. My current code is `<div class="icon"><a class="app" href="apps/settings/index.html"><img style="border-radius:14px;" src="img/settings.png"><p class="label">Settings</p></a></div>`

Comment: add your code then

Comment: The w3schools example itself looks what you are looking for: draggable img to a delimited div. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: are you looking for something like that http://codepen.io/El-Oz/pen/oxrjPa

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for drag-n-drop with "snap to grid" feature.

It is supported by jQuery UI, but since you're not using it, [Gridster](http://gridster.net/#demos) may help.

[Another good library.](https://greensock.com/draggable)

[Pep library](http://pep.briangonzalez.org/) - look at the "Snap to Grid" demo.